# Starting an AsyncTask inside an onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The structure of my class looks like this:

```
class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // ...
        publishProgress();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        // ...
        Task2 t2 = new Task2();
        t2.execute();
    }

    private class Task2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that `Task2` isn't getting executed. Logcat isn't showing any errors either.

I tried executing `Task2` inside a new thread but even that did not work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need Task2 to be another AsyncTask? Any function you put into doInBackground is done on a background thread so using another AsyncTask seems like it may be redundant and overly complicated. Is there any reason why you don't pull the code out of Task2 and put it into a normal function you can call in the doInBackground of Task1?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that will be the way I do it.

Comment: Sounds good. I submitted my comment in the form of an answer. It would be greatly appreciated if you would accept it as the answer. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function you put into doInBackground is done on a background thread so using another AsyncTask can be redundant and overly complicated. You should pull the code out of Task2 and put it into a normal function you can call in the doInBackground of Task1.

Answer (score 0):

"Threading Rules" in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation says that Task instance has to be created on UI Thread. Additionally AsyncTask has to be loaded on UI Thread per the rules. I believe that may be the reason why your Task2 is not executed.

Comment: There's a line in the doc which says `onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).` The confusing part about this is that not even an exception is thrown. It took me a while to debug it and realise that only `Task2` was not getting executed because everything else was working as expected.